# How to set X-Api-Key in the header of HTTP get request

Tags: java, android, get, http-headers

How can i set an x-api-key with the apikey in the header of a HTTP get request. I have tried something but it seems it doesnt work.
Here is my code:

```
    private static String download(String theUrl)
    {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(theUrl);

            URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

            ucon.addRequestProperty("x-api-key", apiKey);

            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

            ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);

            int current;
            while ((current = bis.read()) != -1)
            {
                baf.append((byte) current);
            }

            return new String (baf.toByteArray());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
```

EDIT:
Changed the code with the answer below but still getting an error message:  it couldn't instantiate the type HttpURLConnection(url). I have changed it but now i have to override 3 methods (below)

```
private static String download(String theUrl)
    {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(theUrl);

            URLConnection ucon = new HttpURLConnection(url) {

                @Override
                public void connect() throws IOException {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public boolean usingProxy() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void disconnect() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            };
            ucon.addRequestProperty("x-api-key", apiKey);
            ucon.connect();

            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

            ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);

            int current;
            while ((current = bis.read()) != -1)
            {
                baf.append((byte) current);
            }

            return new String (baf.toByteArray());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of using a `URLConnection`, you should be using an `HttpClient` to make a request.

A simple example might look like this:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(theUrl);
request.addHeader("x-api-key", apiKey);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but after i paste this code into my code. I have to override 1 method (connect). Am i supposed to add  ucon.addRequestProperty("x-api-key", apiKey); inside this method? or is it to late and has there already been an connection established?

Comment: I've updated my answer- you should be using `HttpURLConnection`, as URLConnection doesn't necessarily use HTTP and doesn't have an implementation of `connect()` (whereas `HttpURLConnection` does).

Comment: But i'm getting an error saying that it couldn't instantiate the type HttpURLConnection(url). I'll update my post above what eclipse is saying i have to do.

Comment: My apologies, I forgot `HttpURLConnection` is also abstract. I updated my answer with a better solution that uses an actual HTTP request instead of just a URL connection.

Answer (score 7):

The use of Apache HttpClient is now discouraged. You can check it here: [Android 6.0 Changes](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client)

You should better use URLConnection and cast to HttpURLConnection:

```
HttpURLConnection huc= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
huc.setRequestProperty("x-api-key","value");
```